# How To Get simple re-render counts in react

Tags: reactjs

I use to use [react-perf-tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perf-tool) to get a nice clean count list of which components re-rendered in my app. Now, that shows it's deprecated and I should be using the chrome dev tools.

I must be mis-understanding the dev tools because I can't find an easy way to list my components sorted by the number of re-renders and showing those counts.

Note:

[As of React 16, react-addons-perf is not supported. Please use your browser’s profiling tools to get insight into which components re-render.](https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html)

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you're looking for - https://github.com/amsul/react-performance - a close perf alternative.

Comment: Thanks @natalie.  Do you know what the react team had in mind when they say the built in tools do what's necessary? I just can't figure out how to use the chrome perf tools to get the render info in a manageable way

Comment: BTW, I did try this tool and it feels very intrusive. (react-performance). There isn't an obvious way to use it with functional componets I could figure out